# Storing user activity in client side database

Tags: javascript, database, html, forms

I have been looking at the examples of how to use HTML5 web storage (client db storage). I am trying to build a sample very simple application to see how it works. What I have done is I have created a simple form and submit button in `html`. As of now on clicking the `submit` button nothing happens, as I want to focus on web storage. The code is shown below. What I want to do now is, whenever the user clicks the `submit` button the search query should be stored in my client side database for which I want to use HTML5 web storage. I can capture the user click button using `onClick()` and I want a function to get called which stores the user query. If the user writes something like `software` in the `form` then obviously the query should be stored, something like `user query: software`and if the user leaves the `form` blank and directly clicks the `submit` button and it should show null or blank or something like `user query:`.

As of now, I'm not concerned about whether I use local or session storage specifically, just as long as I use one or the other for now. If any help regarding any storage is provided I can try out the other type of storage (local or session).

My client code `test.html` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <form>
        Search something: <input type="text" name="FirstName" >
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>

<p>Click the "Submit" button and the form will show you nothing as of now! :P</p>

</body>
</html>
```

you can try out the code in any w3schools scrap book or on your own local or web server. Updated code from the below answer is below but it is still not showing anything on clicking the `submit` button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function clickMyStorage()
 {
  if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
  {
    localStorage.setItem("YourQueryGoesHere", value);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Your searched for: " +
    localStorage.getItem("YourQueryGoesHere");
  }
 else
  {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry your browser doesnot support web    storage...";
   }
   return false;
 }

 </script>
 </head>


 <body>
 <form id = "frm1">
 <input id = "nm1" type="text" name="arg1">
 <input id ="toto" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="clickMyStorage();"/>

 <div id="result"> </div>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: So, you just want to store this in `localStorage` (as I assume), but then you say not `local` or `session` -- so where else do you want this?

Comment: please read the question carefully. I want to store in web storage. Web storage are of 2 kinds in HTML5 - local and session. So I don't care as of now about the kind of web storage. I want any type of storage to be working as of now. Later I can figure out the other type of storage on my own

Comment: @user2567857 That sentence was a little ambiguous. It could have either meant "I don't care which I use, as long as I use one of them", or "I don't want to use either of these, I want something else". Reading it in context closely enough would reveal the meaning, but it's not immediately apparent. I submitted an edit to make it unambiguous, as "reading it very carefully" isn't necessary (and can lead to confusion) when being unambiguous is an option.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `localStorage` like so:

```
//inside your submit handler
localStorage.setItem("yourKeyGoesHere", value); //where value is the element you want stored

//retrieve from localStorage
localStorage.getItem("yourKeyGoesHere");
```

`sessionStorage` works the EXACT same way (in terms of syntax, replace `localStorage` with `sessionStorage` -- but they do different things)

Comment: I updated my question with the `localStorage.setItem` code suggested by you but it's showing me nothing when I click the button

Comment: The `submit` button is refreshing the page, `return false` from your function

Comment: done but still nothing is happening on clicking `submit` button. See my updated code in my question - I introduced return in my function

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to put all of the data storage execution within your button click event.

Define your connection,

Define your query commands,

Receive data from each of your form elements,

Open your connection,

Execute your query via POST,

Close your connection,

Decide what to do on the postback (such as clear text boxes or change colors of regions, etc.).

You could also do a postback after the page load event (before your button) to let you know the data submitted to your storage successfully.

Examine the onclick event hierarchy - - there may be something more specific you need to reference to get the data from your custom clickMyStorage onclick event into local storage - - it would be nice to have some data status confirmation logic anyway...